# Create autoinstall flex AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, flex4.5

I'm wondering if there is a way to make an installer (.exe or .air) autoinstaller

So when a user double click it, a silent installation is performed, without asking the destination folder, using instead the default one...

Comment: Why would that be a requirement in the first place? could you elaborate? Of course, there are ways of achieving this. Just trying to make sure you do it for the right reasons.

Comment: I don't actually want a complete silent installer, but at least bypass the destination folder choice... Requirement? Some customers asked that because they have users that are not very good using PC and they want to make the install procedure simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Using the ARH utility](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f117f43a112b21f7d88d-8000)

Following those instructions, you should be able to cook up a custom auto installer that takes parameters, with support for silent installing the air run-time as well.
Keep in mind though that you will need an AIR redistribution license.

Furthermore you could also create a standalone application with the [Zinc Application Toolkit](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/).
I have used it before to create an application that could run from an USB, without the need for the user to install the AIR run-time.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use this cods in a .bat file :

```
CLS
@ECHO off
IF EXIST "%AppData%\Adobe\AIR\eulaAccepted" (
    START myAirApp.exe    
) ELSE (
    START /W AirInstaller\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe  -silent
    XCOPY "eulaAccepted" "%AppData%\Adobe\AIR\"
    START myAirApp.exe
)
```